# Cambiar Servidor y Puerto en MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

Buenas:

Soy nuevo en MongoDB y me he dado cuenta que por default viene en 127.0.0.1:27017, y necesito cambiarlo por mi servidor y mi puerto para poder conectarme a mi servidor en mlab. Agradecería mucho la ayuda

¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Mongo tienes?

Comment: Buenas, En que SO operativo estas trabajando Windows?, Linux?